# Parse error: there is a issue while parsing the package in marshmallow

Tags: android, package-managers

I am getting parse error while installing apk in marshmallow devices.
its working fine in nougat devices.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.graymatic.gmind.mylook"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

and its showing following error in logs

```
/PackageManager: Failed collect during installPackageLI
                                             android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Package /data/app/vmdl1108144592.tmp/base.apk has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml
                                                 at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1176)
                                                 at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1130)
                                                 at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:13205)
                                                 at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$3600(PackageManagerService.java:327)
                                                 at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$10.run(PackageManagerService.java:11017)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                 at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Comment: please add more details :crash log for example

Comment: change your compile sdk version to 25 or 26

Comment: Ranjan, I have changed ,Its giving app no installed error now.

Comment: @ HadjKhelil Nawrez , added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generate signed apk check both `V1` and `V2`
change both `compile` and `target sdk` versions to 27

edit: [image]

check both jar signature and signed apk signature

Comment: how to fix if apk is corrupted.?

Comment: can you please brief about v1 and v2?

Comment: thanks dude. Its working fine now after checking both  . But didn't get whats the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should make both same compileSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.graymatic.gmind.mylook"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
versionCode 1
versionName "1.4"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
multiDexEnabled true

}
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have different values for `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion`, though it would usually be `targetSdkVersion` that has the higher value (i.e. _"I've verified that my app works on devices running Android Y but I'm only using features up to API level X"_ (where Y>X)). Having `compileSdkVersion` > `targetSdkVersion` like OP does seems a bit strange.

Comment: I tried this, its showing me app not installed error

Answer (score 1):

There is also an issue of download place 
In my case in marshmallow i download the apk in `getFilsDir()` then it says parse error 
But if i download it in

```
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

it works fine, no parse error.

`filesDir` works fine in above Marshmallow