# Expo - There was a problem parsing the package Android 12 - S10e

Tags: java, android, react-native, expo, apk

I've been diving around StackOverflow, Medium, and some Google, but haven't found the solution yet.

I'm currently using an ejected Expo App. I need to upgrade the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 31 as [Intercom](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-react-native) currently needs it.

While everything else remains the same, once I change the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to the aforementioned values and download the compiled .apk `eas build --profile development --platform android` I get hit in my S10e (Android 12) with `There was a problem parsing the package.`

I've tried running it on an Android 9 emulator and it fails as well. Nonetheless, a Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android 11 runs it well.

If I downgrade the version to 30, the project resumes and it runs well again.

I've researched all these links (and more)

- [Cant install app from PlayStore for Android 12 targetSDK 31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70620015/cant-install-app-from-playstore-for-android-12-targetsdk-31)
- [apk install failed on android 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71825904/apk-install-failed-on-android-12)
- https://medium.com/@lewwybogus/fixing-there-was-a-problem-while-parsing-the-package-on-android-12-d62365d5a8b
- [What is the use of android:exported="true" in BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458207/what-is-the-use-of-androidexported-true-in-broadcastreceiver)
- [Android Studio error: "Manifest merger failed: Apps targeting Android 12"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412084/android-studio-error-manifest-merger-failed-apps-targeting-android-12)
- [Android 12 (API level 31) can't start ExoPlayer from the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008537/android-12-api-level-31-cant-start-exoplayer-from-the-service)
- [Parse error: there is a issue while parsing the package in marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112493/parse-error-there-is-a-issue-while-parsing-the-package-in-marshmallow)

From what I've gathered, I need to update the `<application>` and `<service>`s tags with `android:exported="true"` accordingly.

I did that, but the .apk is still uninstallable on my device.

Here's the `AndroidManifest.xml` from `src/main`

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="app.omitted">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="44.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/omitted"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="app.pana"/>
        <data android:scheme="exp+pana"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="true"/>
    <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity" android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" android:exported="true"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

eas.json

```json
{
    "cli": {
        "version": ">= 0.47.0"
    },
    "build": {
        "development": {
            "developmentClient": true,
            "distribution": "internal",
            "android": {
                "image": "ubuntu-18.04-jdk-11-ndk-r19c"
            }
        },
        "preview": {
            "distribution": "internal"
        },
        "production": {}
    },
    "submit": {
        "production": {}
    }
}
```

Here's part of the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../android"))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../dist"))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

I don't know what else to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you sign your APK with v2 signing scheme?

Comment: @Pierre Thanks! I don't know! How can I check that? The workspace that I'm currently using wasn't created by me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the merged `AndroidManifest.xml` that resided in the generated `.apk` had several `<activity>` tags that did not included the  `android:exported="true|false"` values. These tags were *not shown* in expo's `AndroidManifest.xml`, and had to be overriden.

One of the main culprits was the Expo dev server.

You need to include an override in the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` (To be honest I didn't know how to include it in the `/android/app/src/debug` folder):

Here's an example on how you do that

```xml
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="44.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <! -- omitted just for reference -->
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<!-- These are the culprits -->
<!-- Include these -->
    <activity android:name="expo.modules.devlauncher.launcher.DevLauncherActivity" android:exported="true"/>
    <activity android:name="expo.modules.devlauncher.launcher.errors.DevLauncherErrorActivity" android:exported="true"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity" android:exported="false"/>
<!-- Intercom is a specific package that I'm using -->
    <activity android:name="io.intercom.android.sdk.helpcenter.collections.IntercomHelpCenterActivity" android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name="com.intercom.input.gallery.GalleryInputFullScreenActivity" android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name="com.intercom.input.gallery.GalleryLightBoxActivity" android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
```

In addition, if your application won't install, is because there may be other tags that need further updates. To check, do the following:

1. Download [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)
2. Create an empty project or open an existing one
3. Go to the Build Tab -> Analyze APK -> Select your expo `.apk`
4. Open `AndroidManifest.xml` and analyze wether all the `<activity>` `<service>` `<provider>` tags have the `android:exported="true"` included.

If you've seen any of them that have not been included, you will need to override them in the `AndroidManifest.xml` within the `src/main` (in case you want to apply it for all the builds - e.g dev, staging, production).

5. You override them by including them INSIDE the `<application>` tag, specify the `name` attribute, and include `android:exported="true"` (or false).

Ex:

```
 <activity android:name="expo.modules.devlauncher.launcher.DevLauncherActivity" android:exported="true"/>
```

Omit all the other attributes and/or children, they will not be removed.

Comment: I wasted hours for this problem. android:exported="true" property solved it. thanks Jose